# .datepicker by input name onSelect does not react

Tags: jquery

I have a simple problem in getting data in data picker when I select it from date box. functions quite simple:

```
var confirm = {
    validate_block: function ($input_planned, $input_confirmed) {
        $input_confirmed.datepicker({
            onSelect: function (date) {
                alert(date);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

where

```
var $input_planned = $("input[name='" + value.planned_field + "']");
var $input_confirmed = $("input[name='" + value.confirmed_field + "']");
```

But it does not work, I'm not getting any reaction from it.

And I have fount the answer, its because class date picker, witch $input_confirmed is a part of, already has date picker configure. Now question can I add this to config or should I make another config with different class.

Comment: Does the datepicker pop up when you focus on the input, or is it just the onselect event that doesn't trigger ?

Comment: datapicker pup up is active

Comment: If the datepicker pop ups, there's not reason the posted code shouldn't work, and [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/67QCs/) shows it does ?

Comment: After using debugger it seems like script enters this section, but when I click date on pop up its completely ignored. Like event is missing.

Comment: But isn't that where you attach the datepicker, so if the datepicker pops up, the code must be running ?

Comment: Aye but I need assign picked date to variable after it has been picked. Like after click it popops out "oh you selected 12.12.2013".

Comment: `confirm` is a javascript function. Be careful using the `confirm` var